# webapp2 jinja2 context_processor

Tags: google-app-engine, jinja2, webapp2

I am building a project on GAE, webapp2, jinja2 and I use [engineauth](http://engineauth.scotchmedia.com/) for authorization. I need something like Django's `context_processor` in order to use session, user and some other variables from **webapp2.request** in templates. Please, help me  to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this.

The simplest way probably looks like this:

```
def extra_context(handler, context=None):
    """
    Adds extra context.
    """

    context = context or {}

    # You can load and run various template processors from settings like Django does.
    # I don't do this in my projects because I'm not building yet another framework
    # so I like to keep it simple:

    return dict({'request': handler.request}, **context)


# --- somewhere in response handler ---
def get(self):
    my_context = {}
    template = get_template_somehow()
    self.response.out.write(template.render(**extra_context(self, my_context))
```

I like when my variables are in template globals, then I can access them in my template widgets without having to pass around bunch of vars in template. So I am doing it like this:

```
def get_template_globals(handler):
    return {
        'request': handler.request,
        'settings': <...>
    }


class MyHandlerBase(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def render(self, context=None):
        context = context or {}
        globals_ = get_template_globals(self)
        template = jinja_env.get_template(template_name, globals=globals_)
        self.response.out.write(template.render(**context))
```

There are other methods in: [Context processor using Werkzeug and Jinja2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539116/context-processor-using-werkzeug-and-jinja2)